# QR Scan Custom Layout

Tags: android, qr-code

By Using Zxing Library. Adding following dependencies in `build.gradle`..
I can scan the QR Code.

> `implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0@aar'
>       implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'`

I want the scan view to display in my own custom layout.. In my layout I have to show a listview below the scan view and at the top of the layout there is a single line header text.

How to implement this?

Answer (score 5):

You should add a ZXingScannerView to your Layout, i.e.:

```
<me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView
    android:id="@+id/scanner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

And get that view in your onCreate() method.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
  ...
  ZXingScannerView mScannerView = (ZXingScannerView)findViewById(R.id.scanner)
  ...
}
```

The activity or fragment have to implement the ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler interface in order to get the QR code.

When you want to start to scan you can create a method similar to this one:

```
public void startScanner() {
     mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
     mScannerView.startCamera();
     mScannerView.setFlash(true);
     mScannerView.setAutoFocus(true);
}
```

And finally get the result in the method handleResult(Result rawResult) from  ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler interface.

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    ....
}
```

That's it. Hope it helps you

Comment: It siply giving me a white blank screen

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add one thing. Did you grant camera permissions before start the camera? OTOH, did you try the https://developers.google.com/vision/ ? In my last project, I removed ZXyng and I'm currently using vision API form Google.

Comment: can u provide a screen shot with custom layout. I found it works only in landscape mode. I already added the camera permission in manifest